# For the ruby on rails guide, need help on understanding how the render works for partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been going through the ruby on rails guide but I noticed something that I cant seem to understand. At the section where it teaches you how to render a partial form for the comment section of the blog. For the partial comments, they used

`<h2>Comments</h2>
        <%= render @article.comments %>`

but for the form they used

```
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render "comments/form" %>
```

Why is it that the first one used @article and not render "/comments"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the difference is, `@article.comments` is a variable from `@article` table entry, however `comments/form` will be a `html.erb` file by the name `_form.html.erb` in `comments` folder.

You can find various use of render on rubyonrails page [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).

Answer (score 0):

It is because it will render the comments partial for each comment on the article object. It's like a 'for' loop without having to know the count of the comments, RAILS takes care of that.
For example: If an article has 2 comments it will render the partial twice.

You can read more about object associations in rails documentation.